# XQuartz problem on OS 10.12.1

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

I In stalled Xquartz from [here](https://www.xquartz.org/), but when trying to start it from the command line via

```
/opt/X11/bin/Xquartz
```

I get an error:

```
> /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO  
  Expected in: /opt/X11/lib//libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO  
Abort
```

Perhaps I'm missing some libraries? Or some of the environment variables is not properly set?

Any help most appreciated.

**edit**

So, I did some research and found out that XQuartz installs its own `libpng.dylib` in `/usr/X11/lib/`, which hence superseeds the system installation in `/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib`. So after

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib /usr/X11/lib
```

the above error disappears only to be replaced with the next:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _gll_noop
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
```

(which hangs). This behaviour persists also if I `unsetenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (found recommended on some sites). I cannot find a library implementing `_gll_noop` ...